# have a problem with Syntax error on line 221 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

Tags: server, apache2, php

I am moving all my files from old server to the new one, i installed apache, but when i try to run it i am getting this error.

> Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 221 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/auth_pgsql.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_auth_pgsql.so into server: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

can anyone provide solution for this error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to  `sudo apt-get install libpq5` to install the postgresql client libraries.

If you had installed the pgsql apache module using a package (`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-pgsql`), the libpq5 package would have been installed automatically, whic makes me think you installed it "by hand" somehow.

Anyway, installing `libpq5` *should* help.